# Using data results immediately after loading from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

I'm having a bit of trouble using data loaded from a JSON file immediately after I load it. Code below.

```
newdata = []

$.getJSON(file, function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            if (item.id != undefined) {
                if (item.id === cl) {
                    newdata.push(item.id);
                }
            }
            });
        });

console.log(newdata);
```

The `console.log` statement doesn't return the data though, it returns an empty array `[]`. However, if I call the variable `data` in my chrome debugger, it returns the correct array. How do I use data with the correct elements immediately after I create it from the JSON file?

Comment: `getJSON` returns data to the callback function in asynchronous fashion. So, `console.log` is executed before the `data` is returned.

Comment: Your `console.log` is firing before your request is complete. The data is available inside the callback exactly as you'd expect. There are something like 200 questions on this exact topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be written like this,

```
newdata = []

$.getJSON(file, function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            if (item.id != undefined) {
                if (item.id === cl) {
                    newdata.push(item.id);
                }
            }
            });
              console.log(newdata);
        });
```

Comment: Made a naming error, the first data = [] should be newdata = []. So logging data would be different from logging newdata. Is there any way to get around the async problem then?

Comment: Updated it to newdata. The async behaviour is how ajax works so you will have to apply your logic within the callback.

Comment: @q2liu The "A" in AJAX stands for "Asynchronous". And you really **don't** want to be synchronous (just think about what that would mean).

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.getJSON` is *asynchronous*. You [should read the documentation on it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to become familiar with how its success callback works.

The function that receives the JSON data is called on success, but the actual `$.getJSON` function returns *immediately* and execution continues. So, in practice, this means that your `console.log(data)` gets executed before the JSON data comes back, but by the time you log it manually in the Chrome console, the data has been retrieved.

The jQuery AJAX methods also return [objects that implement a promise-like API](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), so you can use that, too.

There are many, many questions about this topic on both Stack Overflow and other resources.

The following code uses both the `success` function argument and the `Deferred` object methods. You can do whatever you want with your data in the `handleData` function.

```
function handleData(data) {
    // you can do whatever you want with your data here
    console.log(data);
}

function formatData(data) {
    var formatted = [];
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        if (item.id != undefined) {
            if (item.id === cl) {
                formatted.push(item.id);
            }
        }
    });
    return formatted;
}

$.getJSON(file, formatData).done(handleData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
```

But after being pointed out that the method is deprecated and the better way to do this is given by melc and Thomas Upton.

Comment: The [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) strongly recommends against the use of `jQuery.ajaxSetup`. You can probably set that option on that individual `$.getJSON` call, but why would you want it to be synchronous?

Comment: Also, [see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) that as of jQuery 1.8, the use of `async: false` is deprecated in favor of the `Deferred` methods.